# Can I use a class attribute as a default value for an instance method?

Tags: python

I would like to use a class attribute as a default value for one of the arguments to my class's `__init__` method. This construct raises a `NameError` exception, though, and I don't understand why:

```
class MyClass():
    __DefaultName = 'DefaultName'
    def __init__(self, name = MyClass.__DefaultName):
        self.name = name
```

Why does this fail, and is there a way to do this that works?

Comment: Be sure to read past the less helpful accepted answer to [Ethan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7697664/1709587), which provides working syntax that lets you do this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's because, according to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> **Default parameter values are evaluated when the function definition
>   is executed.** This means that the
>   expression is evaluated once, when the
>   function is defined

When `__init__()` is defined, the definition of `MyClass` is incomplete, as it's still being parsed, so you can't refer to `MyClass.__DefaultName` yet. One way to work around that is to pass a special unique value to `__init__()`, such as `None`:

```
def __init__(self, name=None):
    if name is None:
        name = MyClass.__DefaultName
    # ...
```

Comment: I would prefer not to mention the class explicitly by name. What would be a recommended way to access the class and the class attributes from an instance method?  Is `type(self)` ok?

Answer (score 30):

An important thing to keep in mind with Python is *when* different bits of code are executed, along with the fact that `class` and `def` statements are executed when *seen*, not just stored away for later.  With a `def` it's a little easier to understand because the only thing being executed is whatever is between the `()`s -- so in your code above

```
def __init__( SELF, name = MyClass.__DefaultName ):
```

when Python sees `MyClass.__DefaultName` it tries to find it first in the `local` namespace, then the module (aka `global`) namespace, and finally in `builtins`.

What is the `local` namespace when executing a `class` statement?  That's the fun part -- it is what will become the `class` namespace, but at the moment it is anonymous -- so you can't reference it by name (aka `MyClass` in your code) but you *can* directly reference anything that has already been defined... and what has been defined?  In your class example only one thing -- `__DefaultName`.  So your `__init__` should look like this:

```
def __init__( SELF, name=__DefaultName ):
```

Keep in mind that you can't change `MyClass._MyClass__DefaultName` later and have those changes show up in new instances.  Why?  Because the `__init__` def is executed only once, and whatever value `__DefaultName` had at that moment has been stored away and will always be used -- unless you directly specify a new value when you create a new instance:

```
my_instance = MyClass(name='new name')
```