# Passing self.var (instance attribute) as default method parameter

Tags: python, class

While assigning `num1 = self.var1` in function `fiz`, Python says unresolved reference. Why is that?

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = "xyz"

    def fiz(self, num1=self.var1):
        return
```

Comment: Default values cannot refer to other parameters, including `self`, as they are "not in the same scope". In fact, the values are resolved *before* the method is ever run. This is also why `def f(my_list = [])` does *not* create a new list each invocation.. one way to approach this would be to use `def fiz(self, num1 = None): if num1 is None: num1 = self.var1..` If there is a difference between 'None' and 'not specified', kwargs an be used.

Comment: `self` is not in scope inside the class defintion - you can't have an instance before you've finished defining the class! Just use `None` as a default, then set `num1 = self.var1 if num1 is None else num1` inside the method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Method (and function) default parameter values are resolved *when the method is defined*. This leads to a common Python gotcha when those values are mutable: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761)

In your case, there is no `self` available when the method is defined (and if there was such a name in scope, as you haven't actually finished defining the class `Foo` yet, it wouldn't be a `Foo` instance!) You can't refer to the *class* by name inside the definition either; referring to `Foo` would also cause a `NameError`: [Can I use a class attribute as a default value for an instance method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4041624/3001761)

Instead, the common approach is to use `None` as a placeholder, then assign the default value inside the method body:

```
def fiz(self, num1=None):
    if num1 is None:
        num1 = self.val1
    ...
```

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ because I initially didn't find a duplicate, so wrote an answer, then thought of another search term I could use and managed to find one. And now I can't delete this answer, because it's accepted.

Comment: fair enough, have a nice day +1

Comment: Why is it possible to reference self in the functions attributes, but not as a default value of one of them?

Comment: @HedwinBonnavaud I'm not sure what you're trying to ask, I don't know what _"reference self in the functions attributes"_ means.

Comment: I mean that the first word after the open parenthesis is "self". How is it possible if "there is no 'self' available when the method is defined"?

Comment: @HedwinBonnavaud that's not _referencing_ it, it's _defining_ it. It doesn't have a _value_ to reference until the function gets _called_.

Comment: (Also note those are _parameters_, not _attributes_ @HedwinBonnavaud. Function objects can have attributes too, but that's not what we're talking about.)