# How to Set Default Argument of Class Method Equal to Class Attribute (Python)

Tags: python, class

I have a class like:

```
class Cheetah:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 20
    def move(self, speed):
        ....
```

How can I set the default value of `speed` in the method `move` to `self.speed`?

I've tried `speed = self.speed`, but I get a syntax error.

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Just so if I call `cheetah.move()` and don't pass in a `speed` parameter, it will default to `20`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a class attribute as a default value for an instance method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041624/can-i-use-a-class-attribute-as-a-default-value-for-an-instance-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, but there is no reason to. Default it to None and then just check within the method:

```
def move(self, speed=None):
    if speed is None:
        speed = self.speed
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I thought there might have been a quick trick to do this without the need for an `if` statement, but apparently not!

Comment: Well, you could do it `do_move_logic(speed or self.speed)` for example, but that's not as clear.

Comment: The default for the `speed` argument is set before any instances of `Cheetah` are defined; you *have* to do it this way.

Comment: @Jack What chepner said. Default args are evaluated once, when the function / method is created, not each time it's called.

Comment: Sorry for bringing up this old question. Is there a way to do this smoothly for a variable number of arguments?
e.g. (doesn't work)
`
    def play(self, arg1=None, arg2=None): 
        for arg in locals():
            if locals()[arg] is None:
                locals()[arg] = self.__dict__[arg]
`

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to

```
class Cheetah:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 20
    def move(self, speed=None):
        if speed is None:
           speed = self.speed
        ....
```