# How to define a default argument in __init__ of a class that uses a static class variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, initialization, static-variables

I have an issue where I'm trying to use a static variable as a required named default argument in init of a class:

```py
class Foo:
    bar = 1
    rab = 2
    
    def __init__(self, /, def_arg=Foo.bar):
        if def_arg == self.bar:
            pass
        elif def_arg == self.rab:
            pass

Foo()
Foo(Foo.rab)

4: NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined
```

I also tried without `Foo.` and also tried `self.` but it doesn't work. It has to be specifically static, so I don't want to use self.bar. Is this at all possible?

Comment: If `Foo.bar` is reassigned to a different value, do you want `def_arg` to also change?

Comment: No. But it turns out this was actually a weird Jupyter issue, and it works correctly now when `Foo.` is excluded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a class attribute as a default value for an instance method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041624/can-i-use-a-class-attribute-as-a-default-value-for-an-instance-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use only `bar` it works.

```
def __init__(self, def_arg=bar):
    print(def_arg)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do like this...

```
class Foo:
    bar = 1

    def __init__(self, def_arg=bar):
        self.def_arg = def_arg

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{self.def_arg}".format(self=self)

foo = Foo()
print(foo) # should print 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Default keyword assignments are made when the method is compiled. That happens before the class has been assigned to `Foo`, so `Foo.bar` doesn't exist yet. But `bar` does exist in the enclosing namespace at this point. `def_arg=bar` will grab the current object in `bar` and make that the default argument for `__init__`. Note that once a default argument has been set, it can't be changed. If `Foo.bar` is reassigned, that doesn't affect the default value already placed in the function object for `__init__`.

```
class Foo:
    bar = 1
    rab = 2
    
    def __init__(self, def_arg=bar):
        if def_arg == self.bar:
            pass
        elif def_arg == self.rab:
            pass

Foo()
Foo(Foo.rab)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you made a another func with the @classmethod decorator, you could use the variable as static, like so:

```py
class Foo:
   bar = 1

   def __init__(self):
       print(self.func())
   @classmethod
   def func(cls):
       return cls.bar
```

bar will still be a static variable

Comment: The point isn't to print it. I'm just providing a minimal reproducible example. In my large code I am using 'string' macros to determine the functionality. And I am using one of the defined static variables as the default functionality, and want to give capability of choosing via macros so users don't have to remember strings. Just like opencv does with cv.adaptive_threshold, for instance

Comment: I've changed my answer, sorry for the previous one, I think this one should be more adequate.

Comment: That would work yes, but it still isn't what I'm asking. I know how to work around putting it into __init__ (avoiding it), but I'm curious if it's possible to do it without avoiding it in __init__